# Can I use WF as a replacement to SSIS

Tags: ssis, workflow-foundation

My company has developed many SSIS packages for data transformation for a client. Now client wants to move to cloud and has decided to shut down his data center(so we don't have On-Premise option). As client moves to cloud, we also need to move packages to the cloud (Azure). Since azure does not support SSIS, we now have to change these SSIS packages to worker roles. I have no idea about WF. Someone told me that we can use WF  as a replacement of SSIS packages. My question is , Is it possible? and if so, can anyone please provide link to samples where WF is created for ETL purpose.

Comment: You could use assembler as a replacement to SSIS, but you wouldn't like it very much.

Comment: thanx Siva, MSDN paper talks about VM instance and I don't know client is willing or not?

Comment: @JohnSaunders what is assembler?

Comment: Assembler language: raw computer instructions. It was a joke.

Comment: :) need more sense of humor to understand jokes.

Comment: I think the point of the joke was: yes you can build data integrations in WF, but the language is not as suited to it as SSIS. Regardless it is likely it will cost more for your client to migrate SSIS packages to some other platform (WF or whatever) than they will save by going cloud.

Answer (score 0):

With WF4, you can imitate what SSIS does by building WF activities for the various operations SSIS provides. Its definitely possible, and actually an interesting project. It can be flexible so that your ETL process can target different database engines as well. And it can certainly be setup to work in an Azure worker role with little effort.

Comment: You can "sort of" imitate what SSIS does, but keep in mind, SSIS "does it for a living", and your version will likely be slower. This is especially true for data flows, where SSIS has been improving parallel performance and buffering for quite some time.

Comment: My current shop is also trying to implement the same. I've spoken out about it quite a few times but political winds are blowing in that direction... cannot be stopped. SSIS should be the first option for ETL work on the SQL Server stack.